# If inside ForEach

Tags: php

Here you have my code:

```
<?php
$url = "http://feeds.hipertextual.com/alt1040";
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
if($rss) {
$items = $rss->channel->item;

    foreach($items as $item) {
        $title = $item -> title;
        $link = $item -> link;
        $description = $item -> description;
        $replace = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $description);
        echo utf8_decode("<h3><a href=$link>$title</a></h3>");
        echo utf8_decode("<p>$replace</p>");

    }
}
?>
```

I get the RSS from that URL and I parse it so that images don't appear. Until here OK.
But now, I want only to be shown the first piece of news from the RSS Feed, not all the news.

If I make a count, it tells there are 25 news items.

```
$count = count ($items);
echo $count; //25 news...
```

How can I do to be only shown the first piece of news?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert any number instead of 1 item in this example.

```
 <?php
    $url = "http://feeds.hipertextual.com/alt1040";
    $rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
    if($rss) {
    $items = $rss->channel->item;
    $count =0;
        foreach($items as $item) {
            if ($count<1) {
            $title = $item -> title;
            $link = $item -> link;
            $description = $item -> description;
            $replace = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $description);
            echo utf8_decode("<h3><a href=$link>$title</a></h3>");
            echo utf8_decode("<p>$replace</p>");
            }
            $count++;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: OP is only looking for 1 item.

Comment: misunderstanded, edited answer.

Comment: For me the best answer, as I can choose how many news I want to show. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If your only looking to display the first item, then just set the `$item` variable to the first item array. Then you can skip the entire foreach:

```
<?php
$url = "http://feeds.hipertextual.com/alt1040";
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
if($rss) {
    $item = $rss->channel->item[0];
    $title = $item -> title;
    $link = $item -> link;
    $description = $item -> description;
    $replace = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $description);
    echo utf8_decode("<h3><a href=$link>$title</a></h3>");
    echo utf8_decode("<p>$replace</p>");
}?>
```

Answer (score -1):

why dont you just try to NOT echo the description part?

```
$url = "http://feeds.hipertextual.com/alt1040";
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
if($rss) {
$items = $rss->channel->item;
$isNewsPage = true; // set here to false if you are on main page

foreach($items as $item) {
    $title = $item -> title;
    $link = $item -> link;
    $description = $item -> description;
    $replace = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $description);
    echo utf8_decode("<h3><a href=$link>$title</a></h3>");

    if($isNewsPage)
        echo utf8_decode("<p>$replace</p>");

}
```

Comment: Because I want description part. But only first piece of news in my main website, in the section News, i'll display all the news

Comment: you can easliy put a if statement into a foreach... in the above example you just need to tell your foreach if it is a newsPage or mainpage with a variable or any other condition